# Add seconds on 10 seconds interval based on the value stored in a column using SQL

Tags: sql

Let's. Say table A

```
 Time1.       Col
10:10:00.      3
10:10:10.      1
10:10:20.      2
```

Result

```
Time1       calculated.     Col

10:10:00    10:10:10       3
10:10:00    10:10:20       3
10:10:00    10:10:30       3
10:10:10    10:10:20       1
10:10:20    10:10:30       2
10:10:20    10:10:40       2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses a recursive CTE.  The `recursive` keyword is not used by all databases:

```
with recursive cte (time1, col, n)
      select time1, col, 1
      from a
      union all
      select time1, col, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < col
     )
select time1, time1 + (n - 1) * interval '10 second' as calculated, col
from cte;
```

Note that time functions are notoriously database specific.  This uses standard syntax.

An alternative is a numbers table.  If `a` is big enough, you can just use that (or you might have on laying around):

```
select a.time1,
       a.time1 + (n.n - 1) * interval '10 second' as calculated,
       a.col
from a join
     (select row_number() over (order by time1) as n
      from a
     ) n
     on n.n <= a.col;
```